# Ordinals of the $\varepsilon$ set

Tags: ordinals

I can recall from what I learned about ordinals yesterday that $\varepsilon_{0}$ is the answer to $\omega\uparrow\uparrow\omega$, but what is $\varepsilon_{1}$? I assume $\varepsilon_{1}$ is equivalent to $\varepsilon_{0}\uparrow\uparrow\omega$, but this question is to clarify $\varepsilon_{a}=\varepsilon_{a-1}\uparrow\uparrow\omega$ for $a>0$.

Springing from this question, if this is true, how could you get to $\varepsilon_{\omega}$? $\omega$ is a limit, so you cannot simply say $\varepsilon_{\omega}=\varepsilon_{\omega-1}\uparrow\uparrow\omega$.

Comment: Apologies if this is childish when it comes to ordinals.

Comment: Formulas for the $\alpha$'th epsilon number $\varepsilon_{\alpha},$ as well as for the $\alpha$'th ordinal satisfying $\varepsilon_{\gamma} = \gamma,$ are given in the answers to the mathoverflow question [Set theory: fixed points of $n \mapsto \varepsilon_n$ and $n \mapsto \omega_n$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/418606/15780).

Comment: $\alpha\mapsto\varepsilon_\alpha$ is a *normal function* on the ordinals, meaning it's increasing and continuous. The latter meaning that $\varepsilon$ "commutes with suprema", in this case $\varepsilon_{\textrm{sup}\{n\mid n<\omega\}}=\textrm{sup}\{\varepsilon_n\mid n<\omega\}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you are defining $\varepsilon_1$ as the least $\alpha>\varepsilon_0$ such that $\alpha=\omega^\alpha$, and defining $\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow\omega$ as $\textrm{sup}\{f(n)\mid n<\omega\}$ where $f(0)=1$ and $f(n+1)=\varepsilon_0^{f(n)}$, then yes, $\varepsilon_1=\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow\omega$.

First, a lemma: if there are two sequences $(\alpha_n)_{n<\omega}$ and $(\beta_n)_{n<\omega}$ of ordinals, and $\alpha_n\leq\beta_n\leq\alpha_{n+1}$ holds for all $n<\omega$, then $\textrm{sup}\{\alpha_n\mid n<\omega\}=\textrm{sup}\{\beta_n\mid n<\omega\}$.

Proof: For any ordinal $\gamma$, "$\gamma<\textrm{sup}\{\alpha_n\mid n<\omega\}$" holds iff there is an $n<\omega$ such that $\gamma<\alpha_n$, and similarly for $\gamma<\textrm{sup}\{\beta_n\mid n<\omega\}$ and $\gamma<\beta_n$. If there is an $n<\omega$ such that $\gamma<\alpha_n$, then also $\alpha<\beta_n$, so $\alpha<\textrm{sup}\{\beta_n\mid n<\omega\}$. Likewise, $\gamma\geq\textrm{sup}\{\alpha_n\mid n<\omega\}$ holds iff for all $n<\omega$, $\gamma\geq\alpha_{n+1}$, in which case $\gamma\geq\beta_n$ and $\gamma\geq\textrm{sup}\{\beta_n\mid n<\omega\}$. So $\textrm{sup}\{\alpha_n\mid n<\omega\}$ and $\textrm{sup}\{\beta_n\mid n<\omega\}$ have to be the same ordinal. $\square$

Now, $\varepsilon_1\leq\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow\omega$. It's sufficient to show that $\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow\omega=\omega^{\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow\omega}$, since then $\varepsilon_1$ is the least $\alpha>\varepsilon_0$ where $\alpha=\omega^\alpha$, and $\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow\omega$ would then be an example of such an $\alpha$. $\omega^{\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow\omega}$ is defined as $\textrm{sup}\{\omega^\beta\mid\beta<\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow\omega\}$, and since $\beta<\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow\omega$ holds exactly when "$\beta<\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow n$ for some $n<\omega$" does, this is equal to $\textrm{sup}\{\omega^{\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow n}\mid n<\omega\}$. For each $\omega^{\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow n}$, the inequality $\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow n\leq \omega^{\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow n}\leq\varepsilon_0^{\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow n}=\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow(n+1)$ holds, so by applying the lemma, $\textrm{sup}\{\omega^{\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow n}\mid n<\omega\}$ equals $\textrm{sup}\{\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow n\mid n<\omega\}$, i.e. $\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow\omega$.

An intermediate fact used in the next paragraph is that $\textrm{sup}\{(\omega)_n(\varepsilon_0+1)\mid n<\omega\}$ is also equal to $\textrm{sup}\{\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow n\mid n<\omega\}$, where $(\alpha)_n(\beta)$ is a power-tower with $n$ $\alpha$'s, topped by $\beta$ (for example, $(\omega)_2(\varepsilon_0+1)=\omega^{\omega^{\varepsilon_0+1}}$). By induction on $1<n<\omega$, it can be shown that $(\omega)_n(\varepsilon_0+1)$ is equal to $(\varepsilon_0)_n(\omega)$, then using the earlier lemma, the suprema are equal.

Finally, to show they are the same ordinal, $\varepsilon_1\geq\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow\omega$. This can be shown by showing that $\alpha<\omega^\alpha$ for any ordinal $\alpha$ between $\varepsilon_0$ and $\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow\omega$. Break up the interval between $\varepsilon_0$ and $\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow\omega$ into countably infinitely many "zones", each being a subinterval indexed by a natural number. For $n<\omega$, the $n$th zone consists of all the $\beta$ where $(\omega)_n(\varepsilon_0+1)\leq\beta\leq(\omega)_{n+1}(\varepsilon_0+1)$. These zones cover all the ordinals between $\varepsilon_0$ and $\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow\omega$, because of the intermediate fact. If an ordinal $\beta$ is in the $n$th zone, since $\omega$-exponentiation is increasing, then $\omega^\beta$ is in the $n+1$th zone. Therefore any $\alpha$ between $\varepsilon_0$ and $\varepsilon_0\uparrow\uparrow\omega$ must have $\alpha<\omega^\alpha$, because $\omega^\alpha$ is in a later zone than $\alpha$.

(Why use base-$\omega$ exponentiation and bother with the intermediate fact? In this case it's because $\varepsilon$-numbers are defined using base-$\omega$ exponentiation. Another way of proving this may be to first prove that for ordinals above $\varepsilon_0$, an "$\alpha=\omega^\alpha$" definition of $\varepsilon$-numbers is equivalent to an "$\alpha=\varepsilon_0^\alpha$" definition.)

---

To obtain the same result but for comparing any $\varepsilon_{\delta+1}$ with $\varepsilon_\delta\uparrow\uparrow\omega$ (with a successor ordinal subscript), replace all above instances of $\varepsilon_0$ with $\varepsilon_\delta$ and all instances of $\varepsilon_1$ with $\varepsilon_{\delta+1}$. For the limit case, since $\delta\mapsto\varepsilon_\delta$ is a normal function (therefore continuous), for limit ordinals $\delta$, $\varepsilon_\delta=\textrm{sup}\{\varepsilon_\eta\mid\eta<\delta\}$.